# 16.04 login only background and mouse, can't open terminal

Tags: 16.04, login

I did a fresh install alongside windows by creating the swap area and partition for Ubuntu. Everything on the install worked smoothly but when I login it displays the Ubuntu wallpaper and my cursor that can move. I cannot seem to open terminal through any of the key combos I have read online please help

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to login by going into recovery mode > enable graphic failsafe > enable network > resume boot. When I logged in I opened terminal and ran the following

sudo apt purge 'nvidia.*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-367 nvidia-prime

I then rebooted and loaded straight into Ubuntu from the grub loaded and everything is up and running. Hope this helps others in the future.